# Is it possible to return the parameter of a method into another method in Java?

Tags: java, methods, parameters

For instance, look at the two methods in the code below:

```
public class Customer {

    private Address address;

    public Customer() {
        address = null;    

    }

    public void setAddress(int houseNumber, String postcode) {
        address = new Address(houseNumber, postcode);

    }

    public String getPostcode() {
        if (address == null) {
            return null;

        } else {
            return postcode;

    }
}
```

The *"return postcode;"* line of code is incorrect, I know this, but I want to return only the postcode of the setAddress method into the getPostcode() method. How would I do this?

Comment: `return address.getPostcode ()`  - assuming there is such a method

Comment: Your postcode is already stored inside `Customer.address`, so you can get back your `postcode` by `address.getPostcode()`, assuming that your `Address` has implemented the getter for postcode.

Comment: I know this is a really basic question, but IMO it is nicely formatted and does ask a question which may not be obvious to a total noob, so why the downvotes?  If there is some duplicate, or other problem please comment

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a class `Address` which more likely contains fields `houseNumber` and `postCode`. So to get a `postCode` you need generate getters for `postCode` in `Adress` class and simply write: `return address.getPostCode()`